# good or bad guys in compost bin?

Tags: pests, compost, fungus

I am making this compost at home using green and brown materials (egg shells, banana peel, kitchen waste, dead leaves, green leaves, etc.). While there is no bad smell or any liquid discharge, I recently noticed these three things that I am not sure of whether to kill them or leave them be.

Two of them are some sort of fungus with very bright red cap and one is just like a needle. The other one is some sort of very tiny ball-like red insect. (bottom right in last pic)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the compost's point of view, there aren't many bad guys. Healthy compost can involve all manner of frightening beasts, but unless they are causing other problems (e.g. rats) you can leave the compost to do its thing.

[Here's](https://compost.bc.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/8-Compost-Ecology.pdf) a very informative PDF about the composting food web, and here's a cool diagram showing how diverse the standard soil food web is too!

[image: Diagram of "The Soil Food Web" showing organic matter, plants, nematodes, fungi, bacteria, arthropods, protozoa, birds, and animals interconnected]